# For two functions (one is used inside another) with the same input argument, where to sanitize the input argument?

Tags: php, database, sanitization

For the two functions below, function A uses function B and they take in the same argument - $input. Should this $input argument be sanitized within A or within B? Or should it be sanitized in both? (redundant?)

What is the best coding practice? Thanks!

```
function A($input) {

    // Sanitize $input here?

    B($input);

    // Does its own thing

}

function B($input) {

    // Sanitize $input here?

    // eg. SQL statement using the $input
    eg. "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 = $input"

}
```

Edit: I made this a little more specific so you know what function B does. (let's assume, for example, it uses the $input as part of the SQL statement.

Comment: It depends, but if you ever call `B` by itsself then you need to at least do it there.

Comment: Why not sanitize it outside the functions?

Comment: That’s hard to answer specifically, without knowing anything about what those functions do. This question would make a lot more sense, was it less generic.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @Cbroe...the reason it was kept general is that I want to know if there is a general practice for this type of situation.

Comment: @Ananth, in case another developer uses either one of these functions again (as mentioned by @AbraCadaver), then he might forget to sanitize the input...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the input and what you would want to sanitize. If you would sanitize it in both functions then at least sanitize is using a third function. So that it is handled equally and when you have to change it you have to change it at one point.

You could also use type hinting: [PHP: Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

Answer (score 0):

Sanitize the input in a separate, possibly private scoped, function, calling it at the start of the other functions that would call it. This will allow for consistency and also refactoring the sanitisation to that separate function will reduce the level of work required if you should need to add extra functions that might also need to sanitize input of the same type/range.

Where possible you should use [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) - one advantage of which is that modern IDEs will use this to pop-up hints when typing in code that calls those functions.

Also, as a part of sanitising/validating input values, I'd recommend that you throw subclasses of runtime exceptions to indicate validation errors on that input, e.g.:

```
class My_RuntimeException extends RuntimeException {} 

function A($input) { 
    $s = sanitise_input($input); 
    // do main work... 
}
function B($input) {
    $s = sanitise_input($input); 
    // do main work of this function... 
}

function sanitise_input($input) {
    if (!is_numeric($input)) {
        throw new My_RuntimeException("$input must be numeric.");
    }
    if ($input < MIN_RANGE && $input > MAX_RANGE) {
        throw new My_RuntimeException("$input outside of range.");
    }
    $sanitised = (int) $input;
    return $sanitised;
}
```

This way you aren't relying on cryptic return values to indicate what may be wrong with the input values and you can return the actual sanitised input parameter.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion...where would you suggest this sanitization function be placed? inside of A or B, or outside of both?

Comment: "in a separate, possibly private scoped, function" - call if function C if you will!

Comment: sorry, I meant...where would you call this sanitization function?

Comment: At the start of functions A and B, and any other ones that might rely on it.

function A($input) {
    sanitise_input($input);
   // do main work...
}

function B($input) {
    sanitise_input($input);
   // do main work of this function...
}

Comment: appreciate your inputs very much! however, wouldn't this put in extra server load because your calling the sanitise_input function twice?

Comment: It would to a minor degree, but that should be fairly trivial - it really depends on how much work is involved in sanitising the input. If that proves to be a concern, via benchmarking the code, then you might want to consider caching the sanitised values. Generally speaking though, there should be no need for that.